# PHP says directory is writable, but cannot create a directory

Tags: php, apache, directory, filesystems

I am trying to create a directory named, "sys" under a files directory.

I am testing whether or not this particular location is writable. PHP says yes, but then when I attempt to use the mkdir() function, the directory is not created.

What could cause this?

```
<?php

mkdir("location/files/sys");

$iswritable = is_writable("location/files");

if(!$iswritable) {

echo "Apache cannot write to this directory";

}

else if($iswritable){
echo "Apache can write to this directory";
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this a CLI or SAPI ?
If it is a SAPI script it inherits the webserver user permissions, so if you change the directory ownership to webserver's user (ie. apache, apache2, httpd, www-data, etc.) probably your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running a php script it inherits the Apache user permissions. In that case, you should add "write" permissions for the group/user.

The user/group changes depending on your OS / distro.

In linux (using www-data)

```
sudo chown -R youruser:www-data location/files/
sudo chmod -R g+s location/files/
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe this can help you

```
<?php
    $created = mkdir('location/files/sys');
    if ($created === true) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'cant create dir';
    }
```